# Dhtmlx mobile scheduler month view scroll

Tags: mobile, scheduler, dhtmlx

does anyone know if it is possible to scroll the calendar-month view in dhtmlx mobile scheduler?

[image]

In small devices the calendar view could look like the screenshot above. You have no chance to scroll down for looking to the events of a day. Is it possible to add a scroller to this view?

[image]

Without scrolling it is impossible to see the list of dates for a day like in picture above.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to scroll the Month View in landscape mode. The scroll works only for the list of events in portrait mode.